# Android AsyncTask OutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have an error on my stock quoting application. I have an app where you input your a stock (as in stock market) code and will list it with two buttons. One button to display a quote and the other to view more info from the web. The web function is fine but the app crashes when I hit the quote button.

I think that this is the method in question.

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        try {

            URL url = new URL(args[0]);

            URLConnection connection;
            connection = url.openConnection();

            HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) connection;

            int responseCode = httpConnection.getResponseCode();

            if(responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                InputStream in = httpConnection.getInputStream();

                DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

                DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

                Document dom = db.parse(in);

                Element docEle = dom.getDocumentElement();

                NodeList nl = docEle.getElementsByTagName("quote");

                if(nl != null &&  nl.getLength() > 0) {

                    for(int i=0; i < nl.getLength(); i++){

                        StockInfo theStock = getStockInformation(docEle);

                        name = theStock.getName();
                        yearLow = theStock.getYearLow();
                        yearHigh = theStock.getYearHigh();
                        daysLow = theStock.getDaysLow();
                        daysHigh = theStock.getDaysHigh();
                        lastTradePriceOnly = theStock.getLastTradePriceonly();
                        change = theStock.getChange();
                        daysRange = theStock.getDaysRange();

                    }

                }

            }

        }

        catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "MalformedURLException", e);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "IOException", e);
            } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Parser Configuration Exception", e);
            } catch (SAXException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "SAX Exception", e);
            }

        finally { }

        return null;
    }
```

LogCat is showing that I have an OutOfBoundsException in doInBackground() of my StockInfoActivity class but I can't find it. Will appreciate any help in locating the problem.

```
10-02 02:59:52.738: E/AndroidRuntime(26553): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #4
10-02 02:59:52.738: E/AndroidRuntime(26553): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
10-02 02:59:52.738: E/AndroidRuntime(26553):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
10-02 02:59:52.738: E/AndroidRuntime(26553):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
10-02 02:59:52.738: E/AndroidRuntime(26553):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
10-02 02:59:52.738: E/AndroidRuntime(26553):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
10-02 02:59:52.738: E/AndroidRuntime(26553):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
10-02 02:59:52.738: E/AndroidRuntime(26553):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
10-02 02:59:52.738: E/AndroidRuntime(26553):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
10-02 02:59:52.738: E/AndroidRuntime(26553):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
10-02 02:59:52.738: E/AndroidRuntime(26553): Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
10-02 02:59:52.738: E/AndroidRuntime(26553):    at com.example.stockquote.StockInfoActivity$MyAsyncTask.doInBackground(StockInfoActivity.java:93)
10-02 02:59:52.738: E/AndroidRuntime(26553):    at com.example.stockquote.StockInfoActivity$MyAsyncTask.doInBackground(StockInfoActivity.java:1)
10-02 02:59:52.738: E/AndroidRuntime(26553):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
10-02 02:59:52.738: E/AndroidRuntime(26553):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
10-02 02:59:52.738: E/AndroidRuntime(26553):    ... 4 more
```

Sorry I'm having a tough time isolating the problem.

Comment: post relevant code, we are not going to go searching through your whole project

Comment: The logcat tells you *exactly* where the problem is.  Please post it.

Comment: Please follow @tyczj's advice. Post the relevant code here so that we don't have to go through your question's edit revisions for the link.

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
10-02 02:59:52.738: E/AndroidRuntime(26553):    at com.example.stockquote.StockInfoActivity$MyAsyncTask.doInBackground(StockInfoActivity.java:93)`  Which one is line 93?

Comment: Line 93 is `URL url = new URL(args[0]);`

Comment: Then `args` is empty.  You cannot get the 1st element (`args[0]`) of an empty array!  I suspect that when you call `doInBackground`, you are not passing the array of URLs.

Comment: Thanks. It took a while to search through my code for the missing parameter but I fixed it. If you would like, please provide an answer so I can accept it.